# boost::asio and synchrounous read causing compile errors

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I am trying to make client and server talk and the data being communicated is a vector of structure

`std::vector<element> elemvec`

which is private member of a class, but we have methods to to retrieve individual elements of that vector using `bloom_db.getelem(unsigned int)`.

It is adamantly failing to compile inside boost library code.

I understand that my knowledge on streams, buffers and serialization is highly flawed, but seems I need some hand holding as I don't want to copy code from boost examples.

Following is my code :

```
typedef struct elem{        //This will be seen as a POD (Plain Old Data) in boost::asio::buffer
    bool bit;
    int  count;
    uint64_t  hashSum[2];
    uint64_t  idSum;

    template <typename Archive>
        void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version){
            ar & bit;
            ar & count;
            ar & hashSum[0];ar & hashSum[1];
            ar & idSum;
        }
    }element;

    void sendData(tcp::socket& socket, boost::asio::const_buffer& data)
    {
        boost::asio::write(socket,boost::asio::buffer(data));
    }


    void getData(tcp::socket& socket, boost::asio::mutable_buffer& data)
    {
        boost::asio::read(socket, data);
    }


    void netcom_client(int portn, string serverip, bloom_filter& bloom_db){
        io_service io_service;
        ip::tcp::socket client_socket(io_service);
        boost::asio::const_buffer snd_buf;
        boost::system::error_code ec;
        element snd_elem;
        string bufdata;
        std::ostringstream os;
        boost::archive::text_oarchive out_archive {os};   //archive is connected to global stringstream object
        unsigned int i;

        client_socket.connect(tcp::endpoint(address::from_string(serverip),portn));
        //client sends the data : this loop is to send the data
        for(i=0; i< bloom_db.size(); ++i){

            ::set_elemvec(snd_elem,bloom_db.getelem(i));
            out_archive << snd_elem;            //element inserted in archive
            bufdata = os.str();
            snd_buf = boost::asio::buffer(os.str());
            sendData(client_socket,snd_buf);
        }

        cout<<"Sent "<<i<<" elements from client"<<endl<<std::flush;

    }

void netcom_server(int portn, bloom_filter& bloom_db){
    io_service io_service;
    element recv_elem;
    char bufdata[sizeof(element)];
    boost::system::error_code ec;
    bloom_filter recvd_bloomdb(4,"rcvbloom_db",4096);
    std::istringstream is(bufdata);
    boost::archive::text_iarchive in_archive {is};
    unsigned int i;

    ip::tcp::socket server_socket(io_service);
    tcp::acceptor acceptor_server(io_service,tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), portn));
    acceptor_server.accept(server_socket);

    for(i=0; i<recvd_bloomdb.size(); ++i){
        boost::asio::mutable_buffer rcv_buf  = boost::asio::buffer((void*)bufdata,sizeof(element));
        getData(server_socket, rcv_buf);
        in_archive >> recv_elem;
        recvd_bloomdb.tailadd_elem(recv_elem);
    }
    cout<<"Received "<<i<<" elements at server"<<endl<<std::flush;

}
```

> First Line from Error

/usr/include/boost/asio/detail/consuming_buffers.hpp: In instantiation of ‘class `boost::asio::detail::consuming_buffers<boost::asio::mutable_buffer, boost::asio::mutable_buffer>’:`
/usr/include/boost/asio/impl/read.hpp:45:44:   required from `‘std::size_t boost::asio::read(SyncReadStream&, const MutableBufferSequence&, CompletionCondition, boost::system::error_code&) [with SyncReadStream = boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp>; MutableBufferSequence = boost::asio::mutable_buffer; CompletionCondition = boost::asio::detail::transfer_all_t; std::size_t = long unsigned int]’`
/usr/include/boost/asio/impl/read.hpp:64:39:   required from `‘std::size_t boost::asio::read(SyncReadStream&, const MutableBufferSequence&) [with SyncReadStream = boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp>; MutableBufferSequence = boost::asio::mutable_buffer; std::size_t = long unsigned int]’`
ibflt.cpp:309:35:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/asio/detail/consuming_buffers.hpp:164:5: error: no type named ‘const_iterator’ in

```
‘class boost::asio::mutable_buffer’
     const_iterator;
```

/usr/include/boost/asio/detail/consuming_buffers.hpp:261:36: error: no type named ‘const_iterator’ in

```
‘class boost::asio::mutable_buffer’
   typename Buffers::const_iterator begin_remainder_;
```

Comment: What boost version are you using ? It is < `1.66` ?

Comment: Boost version (currently 1.65)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`boost::asio::read` takes as second argument buffer which must satisfy [Mutable Buffer Sequence requirements](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/MutableBufferSequence.html), in 1.65 class `mutable_buffers_1` does it, not `mutable_buffer` (it will work since 1.66 version).

So change:

```
void getData(tcp::socket& socket, boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1& data)
{
    boost::asio::read(socket, data);
}
```

and

```
boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1 rcv_buf = ...
```

---

```
    std::ostringstream os;
    //...
    snd_buf = boost::asio::buffer(os.str()); // [1]
    sendData(client_socket,snd_buf);
```

The above code cannot work, I mean it compiles fine but it will bring you undefined behaviour. Why?

`boost::buffer` doesn't make a copy of passed data. It returns just tuple (pointer to data and size of data), underlying data is not copied, `buffer` just wraps it.

`ostringstream::str()` returns string by COPY, [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream/str). So buffer takes it, wraps into tuple and at the end of full expression this temporary string is destroyed, hence you have dangling reference in tuple returned by `buffer`.

Solution?

Create named string:

```
std::string str = os.str();
snd_buf = boost::asio::buffer(str);
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. To be honest, I was expecting to get some scolding :), but you were too very polite. I did correct few items in code moments before posting, probably that saved me from the wrath. I updated my boost rather than correcting to mutable_buffers_1